# Connect to SQL Server 2017 using hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server using hibernate and I get this error:

> sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]), detail=(Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment])]

The following is my persistence.xml

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/[databaseName]?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSl=false&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        </properties>
```

And pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Edit

I add this dependency to my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now the error messages has changed.

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
dez 12, 2019 10:40:37 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
dez 12, 2019 10:40:37 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
dez 12, 2019 10:40:37 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
dez 12, 2019 10:40:37 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Falha na conexão TCP/IP com o host xxx.xx.xx.xx/processos_corretivos?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSl=false&autoReconnect=true, porta 1433. Erro: "xxx.xx.xx.xx/processos_corretivos?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSl=false&autoReconnect=true. **Verifique as propriedades da conexão. Verifique se uma instância do SQL Server está sendo executada no host e se está aceitando conexões TCP/IP na porta. Verifique se as conexões TCP na porta não foram bloqueadas por um firewall**.".
```

*Check connection properties. Check if there's an instance of SQL Server being executed in host and if its accepting TPC/IP connections. Check if TCP connections aren't blocked by a firewall.*

Does hibernate just connect with the port?
I can connect to database in MSSMS without the port, but if I use the port I can't connect.

Comment: According to [SQL version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-version-compatibility) you need at least jdbc 6.2 for SQL Server 2017. According to the above, you're using 6.1.

Comment: I just tried  with different versions. Unfortunately, didn't worked.

Comment: Have you checked if your username/password is correct? Looks like your connection to database is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the url.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xx.xx.xx;databaseName=processos_corretivos"/>
```